# Resource Manager pointing to incorrect Module

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, resourcemanager

My Resource Manager seems to be pointing to a non-existent module. The module I'm using should be SwapItAndroid and the RM seems to be pointing to SwapIt_Android.

How do I go about adjusting this so it's pointing to the correct module?